# Failed to open the Parallels networking module

Tags: osx-lion, parallels

I'm running Parallels Desktop 7 on OSX Lion and encounter the issue in the subject on every time I'm trying to launch Parallels VM. The error message contains a hint to restore to network configuration default which does not help. As been advised by some forums to ran the following script:

> sudo kextutil "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_hypervisor.kext"
>   sudo kextutil "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_hid_hook.kext"
>   sudo kextutil "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_usb_connect.kext"
>   sudo kextutil "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_netbridge.kext"
>   sudo kextutil "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_vnic.kext"

The output of:

> sudo kextutil "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_netbridge.kext"

is:

> ---
>
> Diagnostics for /Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_netbridge.kext:
>   Warnings: 
>       The booter does not recognize symbolic links; confirm these files/directories aren't needed for startup: 
>           /Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_netbridge.kext/Contents/CodeDirectory
>           /Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_netbridge.kext/Contents/CodeRequirements
>           /Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_netbridge.kext/Contents/CodeResources
>           /Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/prl_netbridge.kext/Contents/CodeSignature
>
> Dependency Resolution Failures: 
>       No kexts found for these libraries: 
>           com.parallels.kext.prl_hypervisor
>
> ---

I've noticed that prl_netbridge is not being loaded (when I'm trying to unload it, I'm notified it is not loaded).

Am I doing something wrong? What can be the reason for such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that something corrupted or an update has removed some of the required files for Parallels. My best suggestion would be to completely uninstall and remove Parallels 7 following the instruction at [KB112189](http://kb.parallels.com/112189).

Make sure you remove all traces off Parallels apart from the VM's themselves. Then using Software Update to ensure you have the latest OSX Lion updates loaded.

Then install Parallels 7 again, and during the installation insure that it downloads the latest version of Parallels. Once installed, double click the VM file and the error should be gone.

If the error still exists, I think the problem is not related to Parallels, but something on your specific machine and OS specifically.

Comment: I've followed your instructions but it still not working. When trying to launch a VM I'm getting an error message says "Unable to load Parallels driver". After executing the commands I've mentioned in the original post, I'm getting the "Unable to open network module" error. You've mentioned that it might be something with my OS. Any idea what could it be? Gil.

Answer (score 0):

Diago is correct.

In the past, I have gone into the System Preferences -> networks, and removed the Parallels network adapter....

Then simply running the installer for Parallels should resolve the issue.  (A reboot maybe required....)

But this was back in Parallels v5...  I haven't seen this in the last couple of versions...

The complete uninstall may be overkill, but it is a safe method of doing this...  (It may just take a few extra minutes...)

- Benjamin

Comment: I don't see parallels adapter in my network configurations. Gil

Comment: Interesting.  As I mentioned, I haven't needed to do this since Parallels v5 or so.  It seems that they have changed their networking technology since then.  It's no longer listed in my system as well.  Simply re-installing will probably solve the problem then...

Answer (score 0):

After a long session with Parallels' support the solution is to drop the Network from the VM's hardware configuration, recreate it, and restore default networking configuration. The last step would be to manually load the network extension.